# angular 2/ionic 2 - for loop in ts

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngfor

I want to assign `index` to the `content`, in order to add infowindow to markers based on their `index`.

`console.log(storeData.length)` will returns 4 rows of data.

Right now, both method returns me the same result, 4 infowindow overlay with each other. I seem a lot of [examples](http://fiddle.jshell.net/jalbertbowdenii/pGBZD/), however I do not know how to implement to my code. Especially the `var marker,i;`

**TS**

```
for ( let infowindowData of storeData){

  let content = '<ion-item>' + 
     '<h2 style="color:red;">' + infowindowData.ListingTitle +'</h2>' + 
     '<p>' + infowindowData.ListingDatePosted + ' ' + infowindowData.ListingTime + '</p>' +
     '</ion-item>';    

     this.addInfoWindow(marker, content);

}
```

**What I tried**

```
 let storeData =  this.data;

 for(let i=0; i<storeData.length;i++){

 let content = '<ion-item>' + 
     '<h2 style="color:red;">' + storeData[i].ListingTitle +'</h2>' + 
     '<p>' + storeData[i].ListingDatePosted  + ' ' + storeData[i].ListingTime  + '</p>' +
     '<p> Salary: $' + storeData[i].ListingSalary  + '</p>' +
     '</ion-item>';    


 let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
 content: content
 });

 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', () => {
 infoWindow.open(this.map, marker);
 });

 }
```

Comment: `for(i>=0;` ? You surely mean `i = 0`? Also what exactly do you mean by *"it does not run through"*? TypeScript code has to be compiled to JavaScript first, so did you get an error here? What has debugging shown you?

Comment: Also why are you declaring `i` as `any`? It's pretty clearly a `number` here

Comment: @UnholySheep Hi, sorry I put `any` just to test. for debugging, i use `console.log()` before the for loop and within the for loop. the `console.log` before runs on console but the `console.log`within did not appear

Comment: It did not shown any error in the console, but when I tried the `for(i=0;)`, there's no info-window shown. While when I tried with the  `for(let a of b)`, the info-window appears. However it appeared 4 times (I had 4 rows of data) and overlay with one another.

Comment: How are you getting storeData? If it's asynchronously with http, that could be the issue. try doing a console.log before for with storeData.length..

Comment: Why are you wanting to do this instead of *ngFor?

Comment: @JGFMK I could find any reference using *ngFor. I could only find JS examples to follow.

Comment: @JGFMK Most of the google map example with multiple infowindow, all the content are being declared in the in the data. While for my case, my content is multiple data field added together. Thus I'm doing this way. Do you have any other approach to recommend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello why mixing html in the ts? maybe you have a specific reason for doing this but I don't think this is the way you want to go with angular. I would prefer this way by defining that html in a component with input parameters which can be reusable and testable. I am just putting the bare code. if you need additional help, you can ask.

create a component as follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'info-window',
  templateUrl: './component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component.css']
})
export class InfoWindowComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input('title') listingTitle :string;
  @Input('date') datePosted :string;
  @Input('time') listingTime :string;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

The corresponding html is as follows:

```
<ion-item> 
     <h2 style="color:red;">{{listingTitle}}</h2> 
     <p>{{datePosted}} {{listingTime}}</p>
</ion-item>
```

then in your other component where you need to use the above component. See the TS below
//guess storedata is an array

```
private storeData: infowindowData[];
```

your template can be follows. You can decide what to do with the index. You can create an additional input parameter in the component and pass it there. Any additional logic for that component can be done there as well in OnInit.

```
<li *ngFor="let infoWindow of storeData; let index = index">
  <info-window [title]=infoWindow.ListingTitle
[date]=infoWindow.ListingDatePosted [time]=infoWindow.ListingTime></info-window>
</li>
```

Hope that helps.
Ashley

Comment: Sorry, because I trying to add infowindow content to the markers. I learn this at [Google Map Doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows). Do you have any example of other approach for me to learn?

Comment: There are some angular 2 google maps component. https://angular-maps.com/. I have used them once in an ionic projet to display markers on a google map. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Since @ChingChongPa wants index in there too, add {{index}} inside  the <li> then I it looks good to go from me...